# safely restart / reload bind dns

Tags: linux, bind

I have a old  bind dns server (linux centos5.5 with bind 9.3.6)   with 2000+ zone files. Whenever any change is done in any file the dns is restarted. I guess a reload must be sufficient though.

Problem is that a restart takes a long time 50s-60s and dns requests fail during that time.

This must be  a very common issue , What is the correct way of restarting bind

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could reload just the specific zone that was changed:

```
rndc reload zonename
```

rather than restarting the whole server.  That's the simplest way.  I actually do something different on my production DNS:

- Keep all my masters on one separate server (a tiny VM) that services NO user queries
- Use 2 slave servers to service all queries that get all their zones replicated from the master
- All changes get made on master, if a reload is needed only the affected zones get retransferred to the slaves.
- If a reconfig is required (ie changing named.conf to add/delete zones or whatever) schedule that for a maintenance window.

Comment: I've always preferred to have the master copy of your zones on a different server than the one serving your clients. Additionally, and especially on a serving master, you should be checking any changes with named-checkconf and named-checkzone before you reload the zone.

Comment: Skip the filename, i.e. `rndc reload`, to reload the whole thing.

Comment: For dynamic zones, you can `freeze`, `reload` and then `thaw`: `rndc freeze <zone>`, `rndc reload <zone>` and finally `rndc thaw <zone>`. If you try to reload without freezing, you will get `rndc: 'reload' failed: dynamic zone` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132834/293952).

Answer (score 3):

service named reload should also reload and not restart bind.  I agree with others for maximum availability have separate slave bind servers which can serve dns requests if you do need to do maintenance on your master dns server.

Comment: the service seems to be 'named-chroot' on my server, not sure if that is a customisation